# How can this expression be written into the more common form?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How can one rewrite this expression $k^{\ast} = \left(\frac{\delta}{\gamma \cdot A}\right)^{\frac{1}{\alpha - 1}}$ to this expression $k^{\ast} = \left(\frac{\gamma \cdot A}{\delta}\right)^{\frac{1}{1 - \alpha}}$ using common rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the identity

$$x^{a}=\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^{-a}$$

Comment: Thank you, this was the identity I sought. I knew it was something like the known property $x^{-a} = \frac{1}{x^a}$, but this form I totally forgot.

Comment: @Anna no problem! :)